# Radius in Ellipse

Tags: geometry

I found this code on the internet.
 Could you please explain which mathematics formula used in this code? 
I want to learn the formula. What is the name of this formula?
Thanks
[image: Ellipce example here]

Comment: Well, essentially it's saying the following: First we get some value for the radius $r$. Then make a loop so that $x$ and $y$ go from $-r$ to $+r$ with step length $1$. In each step, calculate the quantity $d=\sqrt{x^2 +y^2}$. Then if
$$
\left| r-d \right| < 0.5
$$
then draw a little star (*).

Comment: What is the name of this formula?

Comment: I don't think there is a specific name for the formula. The coder is only using the definition of a circle ($x^2 +y^2 = R^2$) and stretching it with some factors. The condition with the absolute values is only related to the visual drawing part.